# ConversationChain with context in langchain

Tags: python-3.x, chatbot, langchain

I want to create a chatbot based on `langchain`. In the first message of the conversation, I want to pass the initial context.

What is the way to do it? I'm struggling with this, because from what I see, I can use prompt template. From their examples:

```
template = """The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from its context. If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does not know.

Current conversation:
{history}
Human: {input}
AI Assistant:"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["history", "input"], template=template)
conversation = ConversationChain(
    prompt=PROMPT,
    llm=llm,
    verbose=True,
    memory=ConversationBufferMemory(ai_prefix="AI Assistant"),
)
```

But the issue is that my usual approach to working with the models is through the use of `SystemMessage`, which provides context and guidance to the bot. I am unsure if this template is the recommended way for `langchain` to handle system messages. If not, could you please clarify the correct method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ChatPromptTemplate, for setting the context you can use HumanMessage and AIMessage prompt. Below is the working code sample

```
        from langchain.chains import ConversationChain
        from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
        from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
        from langchain.chains import LLMChain

        from langchain.prompts.chat import (
            ChatPromptTemplate,
            SystemMessagePromptTemplate,
            AIMessagePromptTemplate,
            HumanMessagePromptTemplate,
        )

        template = """

        The following is a friendly conversation between a human and an AI. 
        The AI is talkative and provides lots of specific details from its context. 
        If the AI does not know the answer to a question, it truthfully says it does
        not know.

        Current conversation:
        Human: {input}
        AI Assistant:"""

        system_message_prompt = SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(template)

        example_human_history = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("Hi")
        example_ai_history = AIMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("hello, how are you today?")

        human_template="{input}"
        human_message_prompt = HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(human_template)

        chat_prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([system_message_prompt, example_human_history, example_ai_history, human_message_prompt])

        chat = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0)

        chain = LLMChain(llm=chat, prompt=chat_prompt)

        print(chain.run("What is the future of generative AI ? Explain in two sentences ?"))
```